# Raspberry pi GPIO value is always 0

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm trying to change the value of `GPIO port manually`.

To change the value of `gpio18 (physical port 12)`, I did as follow:

```
# gpio unexportall
# echo 18 > /sys/class/gpio/export
# echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction
# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value #output is 0

# echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value #output is 1
```

For `gpio7 (physical port 26)` I perform the exact commands as above. But the value remains `0`:

```
# echo 7 > /sys/class/gpio/export
# echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio7/direction
# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio7/value #output is 0

# echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio7/value
# cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio7/value #output is 0 again
```

I've tried with all other gpio ports. All ports function properly except `gpio7 and gpio11 (the value is always 0)`.

By the way before using this raspberry pi, I was working with another raspberry pi2. Strangely the gpio7 in the previous raspberry pi had the same problem too. Is it a hardware problem or I am doing something wrong?

**EDIt:** I have also used Wiringpi and J4Pi, the result is the same.

Comment: GPIO 7 is SPI's interface CE1 (secondary slave select) pin. You also say that you have same problem with GPIO 11. That's also SPI related pin, that serves as a bus clock for SPI devices. Those can be used as standard GPIO but maybe you have some kind of software trying to use SPI bus that is locking access to that pin?

More info:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md

Also i've just checked commands you've provided on my RPi2 with Raspbian on it. Works just fine.

Comment: @Vir GPIO 9 and GPIO 8 are also SPI but they're working without problem. I've commented out 'spi-bcm2708' in raspi-blacklist.conf file as is mentioned in the link you've provided. Doesn't work.
How can I find out if another software trying to use SPI?

Comment: Sadly I don't know about means to check if something is using SPI. But maybe try fresh install of Raspbian (there's now Lite version that fits on small SD Cards) and check those pins on that one? You said that you've had same problem with other Raspberry that would indicate some misconfiguration of OS for me. I have 3 of them (B+, 2 and Zero) on my desk now and none of them has any problems with those two, or any other, pins so far. Check your Pi's on fresh OS install.

Comment: @Vir I have used another SD card with a new OS. Everything works fine now. Please post your answer to this question so that I can accept it as the answer.